# how to convert multidimention array to arr in object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, for-loop, multidimensional-array

can you explain the logic how to convert this 2d array  to array and in array has objects, here is the input :

```
const arr = [
["Tony", "a", "b"],
["Sara", "c", "z"]
           ];
```

how  to convert them to be:

```
obj = [
{
 name:"Tony", 
 first:"a", 
 second:"b"
},
{
 name:"Sara", 
 first:"c", 
 second:"z"
}
   ]
```

should we create 2 objects temporary and are ? to put them in the array, 
and how about looping? can we just use one-time looping?
and how if that 2d array length is not same with ther 2d on the first or the second,
i do love to know the method, with explaning if you dont mind,
and i do like you all dont use ES6 for this :), so i know the logic

Comment: It turns out you don't even want to use ES5, like `.map`!?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). In the map's callback, extract the values to variables, using [array destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), than create the object with [shorthand property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015):

```js
const arr = [["Tony", "a", "b"], ["Sara", "c", "z"]];

const result = arr.map(([name, first, second]) => ({
  name,
  first,
  second
}));

console.log(result);
```

And if you don't want to use `Array.map()`, you can build one using a `for...of` loop:

```js
const map = (arr, cb) => {
  const r = [];
  
  for(const item of arr) {
    r.push(cb(item));
  }
  
  return r;
};

const arr = [["Tony", "a", "b"], ["Sara", "c", "z"]];

const result = map(arr, ([name, first, second]) => ({
  name,
  first,
  second
}));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: how about  if we dont use map?? @ori

Comment: map is like a magic, i want to learn by logic and by old style method, :D,

Comment: Map is not magic at all. You can build a map easily using a `for...loop` - http://awanderingreader.com/javascript-under-the-hood-building-our-own-foreach-and-map-functions/

Comment: @ZrClassic - I've added an example of a magicless map using for...of.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `.map()` with some array destructuring:

```js
const arr = [
  ["Tony", "a", "b"],
  ["Sara", "c", "z"]
];

const result = arr.map(([name, first, second]) => ({name, first, second}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Alternatively, you can use a simple for loop:

```js
const arr = [
  ["Tony", "a", "b"],
  ["Sara", "c", "z"]
];

const result = [];

for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  result.push({
    name: arr[i][0],
    first: arr[i][1],
    second: arr[i][2]
  });
}

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var arr = [["Tony", "a", "b"], ["Sara", "c", "z"]];

function parseData(input){ 
    var output = [];
    for(var i = 0; i< input.length ; i++){
        output.push({name:input[i][0],first:input[i][1],second:input[i][2]})
    }
    return output;
}
console.log(parseData(arr));
```

**EDIT - Explanation**

As the input is structured as 2D array with inner array is of fixed length of 3 and outer is of non-negative ( >= 0 ). Iterate over the outer array using `for` loop and inner array using the index number and store the result in `output` array.

JsFiddle demo - https://jsfiddle.net/53umf8rv/

Comment: Since your answer may be a good answer, it still needs more explainations about the changes and how it works.

Comment: @TânNguyễn Explanation added as requested.

Answer (score 1):

Without Map:

```
const arr = [
["Tony", "a", "b"],
["Sara", "c", "z"]
           ];

obj=[]; 
for(innerArr of arr)
{
obj.push({"name":innerArr[0],"first":innerArr[1],"second":innerArr[2]});
}

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

Without using higher order functions you can achieve this using a `for of` loop:

```js
const arr = [
  ["Tony", "a", "b"],
  ["Sara", "c", "z"]
];

let obj_arr = [];

for(inner_arr of arr) {
  obj_arr = [...obj_arr, {name: inner_arr[0], first: inner_arr[1], second: inner_arr[2]}];
}

console.log(obj_arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use an outer [`for ... of` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of), which iterates the items of the array and iterate the inner array by using a classic [`for` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) with an index variable, which is used to get the corresponding key value as well.

For each inner iteration take a new property for the temporary object and assign a value. At the end of the inner iteration push the temporary object to the result set.

```js
function convert(array, keys) {
    var result = [],
        items,
        i,
        temp;
    
    for (items of array) {
        temp = {};
        for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            temp[keys[i]] = items[i];
        }
        result.push(temp);
    }
    
    return result;
}

console.log(convert([["Tony", "a", "b"], ["Sara", "c", "z"]], ["name", "first", "second"]));
```